# ActiveRecord Rollback Multiple Transactions

Tags: mysql, ruby, activerecord

I have a function to save some data to multiple tables in the same mysql database.
Inside the function,

```
def process_data(dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD)
# let's say dataA is saved to tableA, dataB to tableB, dataC to tableC, dataD to tableD
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do   
   begin
       tableA.create(:dataA => dataA)
       tableB.create(:dataB => dataB)
       tableC.create(:dataC => dataC)
       tableD.create(:dataD => dataD) # let's say error occurred here
   rescue
       ActiveRecord::Rollback
   end
end
end
```

If there is an exception while creating new tableD record, I want to rollback everything (dataA, dataB, dataC).

How can I achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raise ActiveRecord::Rollback inside of your transaction block if you need to rollback

```
def process_data(dataA, dataB, dataC, dataD)
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do   
   begin
       tableA.create(:dataA => dataA)
       tableB.create(:dataB => dataB)
       tableC.create(:dataC => dataC)
       tableD.create(:dataD => dataD) # let's say error occurred here
   rescue
       # will rollback on any exception
       raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
   end
end
end
```

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html for more info.

Comment: adding `raise` fixed it. Thank you.